# hive iterate over elements in array after splitting, or split on 2 separators

Tags: hive

is there a way to split a string in hive on 2 separators and in order, or perform and split, and iterate over each element in the array and split again?

For example:

string in question =

```
"123=apples;456=oranges"
```

If I split, `SELECT split("123=apples;456=oranges", ";")` I'll get an array `["123=apples", "456=oranges"]`, but I'd also like to split on `=` within this new array.

Looking to do this in pure SQL for Hive.

Comment: **(1)** Hive and Spark are two different products. **(2)** Welcome to the https://xyproblem.info/ club. What are you really asking for? What is your endgame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select map_values(str_to_map("123=apples;456=oranges", ";", "="))
```

| _c0 |
| --- |
|  |
| ["apples","oranges"] |

Comment: This is what I came up with too, but forgot to update here! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `split` in Hive actually support the regex string in Java regular expression, you can just do it by

```
SELECT split("123=apples;456=oranges", "\=|\;")
```